# Anglar Forms, need some simple examples

Tags: angular, forms

A lot of the official tutorials I'm seeing seem too robust.

I have a user class with "name" and "password" strings.

I need a form that takes user input from these two and writes it to the object.

Then posting it to the table in the database.

I'm new to Angular, I didn't think such simple forms would be so complex.

Answer (score 2):

here's a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f1jkfu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) example.

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpClientModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent  {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService){}

  fg = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(),
    password: new FormControl()
  })

  onSubmit(){
    this.authService.login(this.fg.value).subscribe();
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="fg">
    <div>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input id="username" type="text" formControlName="name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" formControlName="password">
  </div>
  <button>Login</button>
</form>
```

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
  login(data: any) {
    return this.httpClient.post("your url", data);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the bare minimum using reactive forms. With template driven forms it would be less code, but I don't prefer them. This is without validation, and when initializing  the form group you could use FormBulder. That reduces the code even more, but that's just code sugar.